# JavaScript setTimeout in for Loop for Performance Test

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I am trying to use setTimeout for a performance test using console.time() and console.timeEnd(). However, setTimeout() isn't delaying the for() loop.

Here is the JS Fiddle:

```js
// Start the timer.
console.time('testFor');

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  setTimeout( console.log('The number is ' + i), 2000 );
}

// End the timer, get the elapsed time.
console.timeEnd('testFor');
```

How can I make setTimeout() work in my script and why is it not working for me?

Comment: asynchronous 101, not going to happen.

Comment: `setTimeout` is *not* a `sleep` command.  `setTimeout` basically tell JavaScript to run the function 2000ms in the future.

Comment: Also, you need to pass a *function* to `setTimeout`.  In your code, the `setTimeout` is doing nothing, since you call `console.log` immediately and pass its return value to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already suggested excellent solutions to your problem - I'd like to offer a closer examination of what was happening with your code.

`setTimeout` doesn't delay the advancement of your code (like `sleep` does in other languages) but instead defers running another block of code.  It's a weird concept that can be hard to understand; consider the following example:

```
console.time("Main Program");
console.time("Defered Code");

setTimeout(deferedCode, 1000);

console.timeEnd("Main Program");

function deferedCode() {
    console.timeEnd("Defered Code");
}
```

If we look at the console after running this code, we'll see "Main Program" print out almost immediately, and "Defered Code" roughly a second later.

We've asked `setTimeout` to run the function `deferedCode` at a time 1000 ms in the future, and then let the rest of the code run.

Notice also that `deferedCode` is passed to `setTimeout` without `()`.  We're passing the function itself and not the result of `deferedCode` to `setTimeout` so that `setTimeout` can choose when to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without a loop, just using recursion:

```
var i = 0;

var logNumber = function(){
    console.log('The number is ' + i);
    i++;
    if(i < 5){
        setTimeout(logNumber, 2000);
    }
}

logNumber();
```

Comment: Don't you mean `setTimeout(logNumber, 2000);`?

Comment: Cool, but is there a way I can do it without recursion? Maybe with an enclosure?

Comment: Check out @Andrew D's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is asynchronous.  If you want to call a certain piece of code at regular intervals, use the setInterval function.

I think this code is close to what you are trying to do:

```
// Start the timer.
console.time('testFor');

var i = 0;
var finish = 5;
var t = setInterval(function() {
  if (i < finish) {
    console.log('The number is ' + i);
    i++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(t);
    // End the timer, get the elapsed time.
    console.timeEnd('testFor');
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Argh! Too complicated for me as a n00b. Assigning a function to a variable is very confusing to me.

Comment: I'm not assigning a function to a variable.  I'm assigning the return value of the setInterval function call to a variable.  setInterval returns an ID which we can later pass to clearInterval to stop things.

Comment: The setInterval function takes two parameters - the first being the function you want called at each interval, and the second being the number of milliseconds you want between each call. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp